# Filter one table based on collection of values and one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have Web Application where allow to filter `Person` by collection of `Name`. This should return all `Person` whose `Name`s have all sended values (extended when: for all `value` in `values` exists one `Name` which contain that `value`)

Model was defined as two tables: `Person` and `Name` (and matching C# classes) (other columns/properties omitted for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Name](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Name] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Name_Person] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Person]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I wrote simple EF Core query

```
// basic
_context.Set<Person>().Where(p => values.All(value => p.Names.Contains(value))); 

// extended
_context.Set<Person>().Where(p => values.All(value => p.Names.Any(n => n.Contains(value))));
```

but none of them were translated to SQL and filtering were performed in memory. So I try to write SQL query (and maybe translate it back if possible), but I cannot find out how to do it correctly.

One of idea was:

```
select * from Person
where 
Id in 
(
    select distinct PersonId from PersonName where CHARINDEX('value1', Name, 0) > 0
)
and
Id in 
(
    select distinct PersonId from PersonName where CHARINDEX('value2', Name, 0) > 0
)
```

(and add new `in` clause for each `value` in `values`)

but isn't it inefficient?

I also read https://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html as study case, but firstly I want to achieve it without changing model

------------------------- SAMPLE DATA -------------------------

```
Person      Name
------      ---------------------------
| Id |      | Id | PersonId | Name    |
------      ---------------------------
|  1 |      |  1 |        1 | James   |
------      ---------------------------
|  2 |      |  2 |        1 | Jacob   |
------      ---------------------------
|  3 |      |  3 |        2 | Jacob   |
------      ---------------------------
            |  4 |        2 | Michael |
            ---------------------------
            |  5 |        3 | Mike    |
            ---------------------------
```

```
// basic (exact matching)
-------------------
| Input | Result  |
-------------------
| Jacob | 1, 2    | Both 1 and 2 has Jacob in Name
-------------------
| Mike  | 3       | Only 3 has Mike in Name
-------------------

// extended (any contains)
-------------------
| Input | Result  |
-------------------
| j, m  | 1, 2    | 1: james (both "j" and "m"), 2: jacob, michael 
-------------------
| m     | 1, 2, 3 | All persons have name containing "m"
-------------------
| mi    | 2, 3    | 2: michael, 3: mike
-------------------
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data for your tables and what value you are searching for. it will help to understand your problem.

Comment: Added example data and input with expected results. There were more columns in Person but were omitted for clarity. 
User ask: Give me all persons with names: `Jacob, Mike` and expect persons which have all of them (but can have more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Alan Burstein answer I created (for extended version)

```
select N.PersonId from (values ('j'), ('m'), ('i')) AS Input(Value)
join Name as N on CHARINDEX(Input.Value, N.Name) > 0
group by N.PersonId
having count(distinct Input.Value) = 3
```

which does not use concatenation. Compared on 125k `Name`s and 125k `Person`s

```
This:
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 672 ms,  elapsed time = 700 ms.

Alan's: (with replaces splitting input to table by "values" and counting of elements by "3")
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2547 ms,  elapsed time = 2560 ms.
```

But still 700ms is probably a lot

Answer (score 1):

First for some easily consumable sample data:

```
INSERT dbo.person VALUES (1),(2),(3); -- note: for this I dropped/re-added the identity column
INSERT dbo.[Name] (PersonId, [Name]) VALUES 
(1 ,'James'  ),
(1 ,'Jacob'  ),  
(2 ,'Jacob'  ), 
(2 ,'Michael'),
(3 ,'Mike'   );
```

Next, you are asking two things here each with "child requests". This is not a complaint just something worth noting; let's take them one at a time.

### Exact Matching Logic

(1) Returning the rows we need:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Jacob';

SELECT   n.PersonId
FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n
WHERE    n.[Name] = @name;
```

(2) Concatenating the return values into a single row:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Jacob';

SELECT Input = @name, Result = STUFF((
                                 SELECT   CONCAT(',',n.PersonId)
                                 FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n
                                 WHERE    n.[Name] = @name
                                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

**Returns:**

```
Input     Result
--------- ---------
Jacob     1,2
```

(3) Retrieving the correct result for all names in dbo.Name:

```
SELECT f.Input, f.Result 
FROM dbo.[Name] AS np
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT Input = np.[Name], Result = STUFF((
                                   SELECT   CONCAT(',',n.PersonId)
                                   FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n
                                   WHERE    n.[Name] = np.[Name]
                                   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
) AS f
GROUP BY f.Input, f.Result;
```

**Returns:**

```
Input       Result
----------- --------
Jacob       1,2
James       1
Michael     2
Mike        3
```

### CONTAINS Logic

(1) For this to work we need to pseudo-pivot the results into full names like this:

```
SELECT n.PersonId, FullName = 
(
  SELECT   ' '+n2.[Name] 
  FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n2
  WHERE    n.PersonId = n2.PersonId
  ORDER BY n2.id
  FOR XML PATH('')
)
FROM   dbo.[Name] AS n
GROUP BY n.PersonId
```

**Returns:**

```
PersonId  FullName
--------- ---------------------
1          James Jacob
2          Jacob Michael
3          Mike
```

(2) To split strings into an array of values we'll need to to split (tokenize) the input and trim the results. For this I'm using `STRING_SPLIT` if you are on a pre-2016 system you'll need something else (google: delimitedsplit8k):

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'j, m';

SELECT      v = LTRIM(s.[value])
FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@name,',') AS s
```

(3) Now we'll combine this logic to split the input and search each record for a match.

*Note that I added a new value to your input:*

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'j, m, i';

WITH a AS
(
  SELECT n.PersonId, FullName = 
  (
    SELECT   ' '+n2.[Name] 
    FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n2
    WHERE    n.PersonId = n2.PersonId
    ORDER BY n2.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )
  FROM   dbo.[Name] AS n
  GROUP BY n.PersonId
)
SELECT      a.PersonId--, a.FullName--, x.x
FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@name,',') AS s
JOIN        a ON CHARINDEX(LTRIM(s.[value]),a.fullname) > 0
GROUP BY    a.PersonId;
```

**Returns:**

```
PersonId
-----------
1
2
3
```

As you can see it's returning *everyone **because*** it's returning values where ANY of the letters match. We want only rows where ALL letters are contained. For that we'll add: `HAVING      COUNT(*) >= LEN(@name)-LEN(REPLACE(@name,',',''))+1`

(4) The final solution here, with an input of `@name = 'j, m, i'` should only return ID 2, for **J**acob **Mi**chael

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'j, m, i';

WITH fullnames AS
(
  SELECT n.PersonId, FullName = 
  (
    SELECT   ' '+n2.[Name] 
    FROM     dbo.[Name] AS n2
    WHERE    n.PersonId = n2.PersonId
    ORDER BY n2.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
  )
  FROM   dbo.[Name] AS n
  GROUP BY n.PersonId
)
SELECT      a.PersonId--, a.FullName--, x.x
FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@name,',') AS s
JOIN        fullnames AS a ON CHARINDEX(LTRIM(s.[value]),a.fullname) > 0
GROUP BY    a.PersonId
HAVING      COUNT(*) >= LEN(@name)-LEN(REPLACE(@name,',',''))+1;
```

Comment: Based on your solution I tried to remove concatenation and rewrite it to ```select N.PersonId from (values ('j'), ('m'), ('i')) AS Input(Value)
join Name as N on CHARINDEX(Input.Value, N.Name) > 0
group by N.PersonId
having count(distinct Input.Value) = 3
```, which is faster (125k `Name`s and 125k `Person`s).

Answer (score 0):

Did not get why "| j, m  | 1, 2    |" covers "Michael", but does not cover "Mike"

```
DECLARE @PersonName TABLE (name [nvarchar](max), PersonId INT)
INSERT INTO @PersonName(name, PersonId ) VALUES  ('James',1),('Jacob',1),('Jacob',2),('Michael',2),('Mike',3);

SELECT CAST((select CAST(PersonID AS VARCHAR) + ', '
FROM @PersonName as n 
WHERE name like '%Jacob%' 
FOR XML PATH('')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT CAST((select CAST(PersonID AS VARCHAR) + ', '
FROM @PersonName as n 
WHERE name like '%m%' and name like '%j%' 
FOR XML PATH('')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT CAST((select CAST(PersonID AS VARCHAR) + ', '
FROM @PersonName as n 
WHERE name like '%m%' 
FOR XML PATH('')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT CAST((select CAST(PersonID AS VARCHAR) + ', '
FROM @PersonName as n 
WHERE name like '%mi%' 
FOR XML PATH('')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: About exampe with `j, m`. `Michael` only cover `m`, and `Jacob` cover `j`. Therefore person with Id:2 is a match. Id:3 have only matched `m` by `Mike` but there is no name with `j`